# Postgres casting field before applying index

Tags: postgresql, date, indexing, casting

I have a table with ~10mln rpws that I am querying with date constraint. There's a column `dt` of type `date` ( format `YYYY-MM-DD` ). I have created an index on it: `CREATE INDEX dt_dx ON TABLE table(dt)` . I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on it that returned this:

```
Index Scan using dt_idx on entities  (cost=0.56..74175.26 rows=218 width=64) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=0 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: ((dt)::text = '2017-07-26'::text)
```

Does it mean that **Postgres** is casting column's data to `text` before comparing values to the query parameters?

Comment: Yes, are you comparing that date to a text? If you want you can cast your text to date and then it won't convert the date to text, since they'll now match types.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe I thought that Postgres will figure out that my `2017-07-26` should be compared to `dt` field as date since: 1) `dt` is of type `date`; 2) it has proper format for `date`.

Comment: The default for stuff with ' quotes around it is text unless otherwise casted. Give it a try like I said and see if it matches direct and runs any faster.

Comment: Note that it's all about how many casts pg has to throw at this. If it's a thousand rows no biggie, if it's 10M then it starts to add up.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe thanks for your involvement. I don't think I understand what you mean though. I tried querying without quotes around my date parameter like this: `where dt = 2017-07-26` but I get error message: `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` . Similarly if I try casting it to `date` like this: `where dt = \`2017-07-26\`::date` I get the same error message.